# Validate KeyStore password in Java

Tags: java, keystore

I'm allowing the user to specify its own KeyStore in my application.
I'd like to validate that KeyStore password, given by the user, is valid.
Is there a way doing that?

Comment: Yes. Open the keystore with the password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try loading it

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
/* getting the key*/
keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
```

Throws:
`IOException` - if there is an I/O or format problem with the keystore data, if a password is required but not given, **or if the given password was incorrect**. If the error is due to a wrong password, the cause of the IOException should be an UnrecoverableKeyException